# Is this a safe way to start and stop a thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading

Say I have a class called `foo` which executes some task in a thread. I want to start and stop this task as I see fit. My code is the following:

```
class foo
{

public:
    foo() {};
    ~foo() {};

    void start_thread() {
        thread_active = true;
        the_thread = std::thread(&foo::execute, this);
    }
    void stop_thread() {
        thread_active = false;
        the_thread.join();
    }

private:
    void execute() {
        while (thread_active)
            std::cout << "executing...\n";
    }

    std::thread the_thread;
    bool thread_active;
};
```

where I call it like so:

```
int main()
{
    foo bar;
    bar.start_thread();
    Sleep(1000);
    bar.stop_thread();
}
```

Is this a safe way to do so?

Comment: I'ld make `thread_active` `std::atomic<bool>
`.

Comment: You need to protect the concurrency on thread_active using a mutex or std::atomic as suggested by the previous comment.

Comment: The example will still work on `x86` and `arm` with memory fence after write operation.

Answer (score 3):

No, this is not a safe way.

The reason is that the `thread_active` member is accessed without synchronization from multiple threads in read and write, you should declare it `std::atomic_bool` or use some other form of synchronization.

Comment: Could you elaborate (i.e. provide an example) of another form of synchronization?

Comment: @JimBob: you could use an `std::mutex`, acquiring a lock istantiating an `std::lock_guard` before reading or writing to it (seems overkilling in this case, tho).

Comment: Could you please explain: what exactly is not safe? Is there a risk of running one extra `while` loop iteration in the thread, or is the risk that the thread will never exit?

Comment: @VladFeinstein: if you write a location from a thread and read the same location from another without a synchronization then you're in UB land and anything can happen. Compiler authors (and even CPU designers) are free to ignore to handle those behaviours because a programmer is not supposed to do that.

Comment: @VladFeinstein If you don't use any form of synchronization to access `thread_active`, the compiler is free to assume that `thread_active` is not modified from another thread. If you replace `std::cout << "executing...\n";` with something for what a smart enough compiler (clang, for example) can infer that it neither modifies `thread_active` nor contains any form of synchronization, your thread will never exit.